# Beaglebone black with node red autostart problem

Tags: node-red, autostart

I have some problem about autostart node red when power up beaglebone untile I go to the browser to the ip address in my case: 11.21.31.20:1880 it don’t start node red as soon as the I go to the IP address flow is loaded and node red start working. Ho can be solved this? Thanks

Comment: Flows are always started as soon as Node-RED starts (unless safemode is enabled). Without seeing the Node-RED logs there is very little else that can be said.

Comment: How can I get the log? Thanks

Comment: No idea, it will depend on how it's configured to start and possibly how you installed it.